# Сделать письма редактируемыми через инфоблоки в Bitrix

Tags: вёрстка, битрикс

**Есть такая задача:** есть верстка email.

Нужно каким то образом в те области, что клиент захочет редактировать, прикрутить инфоблоки.

То есть, чтобы человек зашел, отредактировал какую то область и это все автоматом сохранилось.

Например в шаблон письма, готового к отправке. Или еще каким то методом

**Вопрос:** есть идеи, как реализовать?

Comment: Так надо править шаблон, по которому будут формироваться письма? Ил править готовые письма перед отправкой?

Comment: Но ведь правка шаблонов и подстановка данных из инфоблоков в модуле email-маркетинг уже есть. А для остального прописывайте макросы для шаблонов и заполняйте их чем хотите.